# Gluon Mobile app slows down when switching Views

Tags: android, javafx, javafxports, gluon, gluon-mobile

When switching Views multiple times, the app runs slower and slower.
On Desktop you cant really see the difference, because it has enaugh RAM.
But on my Android device something seems to build up so that the app slows down.

This happens in the example App with multiple views (using afterburner) when you switch fast between Primary and Secondary many times (about 30+).

Is this caused by animations building up (View transitions) or is this caused by the views themselves?.

Is there a way to fix this? Or is it a bug?

I traced the View Events:
Primary event: SHOWING
Primary event: SHOWN
Primary event: CLOSE_REQUEST **<-- Why this one? is Hiding not enaugh?**
Primary event: HIDING
Primary event: HIDDEN

(I tried setting the ViewStackPolicy to SKIP but that doesnt help either)

And if you know how Gluon handles Views on Android, please share :D

**EDIT:**
This even happens with the example application (Multiple Views FXML) on my Samsung Galaxy S5.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. We are running some tests to check it. What Android device do you have?

Comment: @LucaZ Are you sure that you release all listeners that you have registered in your application when you switch your views? It is easy in JavaFX to get that wrong by just using some innocent looking lambda expressions.

Comment: @mipa I didn't even know you had to do that (im new to JavaFX).  
I'll look further into it, if the problem persists I will comment again.